# makefile flags for debugging (needs symbolic information) -g flag didn't work

Tags: c, debugging, makefile, debug-symbols

I am working on a makefile and trying to compile it for debugging (I added -g and -Wall flag). Here are the relevant parts:

```
LDFLAGS     =-L$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib -L$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/lib -L../../lib

INCLUDE     =-I$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/demo -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/public -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/plsql/public -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/network/public -I$(COMMON_SRC) -I$(BNS_INCLUDE) -I. 

CFLAGS      =$(INCLUDE) $(LDFLAGS) -g -Wall -Xt
```

**Error:**
I am trying to compile in unix and get an error:

```
cc: illegal option -Wall
*** Error code 1
clearmake: Error: Build script failed for "bess_interface.o"
```

I recall using `-Wall` before on Linux/Cygwin.

**Question:**

> Why am I getting the `-Wall` error? Is it not a valid flag?

**Note:**
I initially I had:

```
CFLAGS      =$(INCLUDE) $(LDFLAGS) -g -Xt
```

and when I was trying to debug I'd get an error saying:

> No symbolic information for "main". Compile with `-g` flag.

But the `-g` flag was right there!

Comment: What is your compiler? If it's not GCC then it might need other flags.

Comment: Are you on Solaris and using SUN's Forte compiler?

Answer (score 3):

`-Wall` is to enable all warnings on GNU compiler.

For SUN's Forte compiler use [-errwarn=%all](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5267/bkapl/index.html).

The compile for debugging flag is still `-g`.

Comment: +1 this makes properly; however my workshop debugger application still can't find symbols

Comment: Are you still receiving the "Compile with -g flag" message?

Comment: yes I am; I'll try to find out the debugger (but I'm told it is gcc). Maybe my workshop app can't see the .o files.... hmmm

Comment: @Adrian: The debugging symbols should be in your executable, it is unlikely that debugger looks into `.o` files. Check that you don't strip symbols with e.g. `install` after your executable is build. If that is OK, tell us what is your debugger (alternatively try `gdb` as a "reference" debugger). If `gdb` is failing, try to play with [debugging options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options).

Comment: @Adrian, just in case yo areu unaware `dbx` is Sun's debugger.